# Laravel - Add dynamically image with Angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I want to input image's src value with Angular. Here is my code :

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <img src="{{asset('assets/img/'.'/'.  @{{ item.name }} )}}">
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items =
    [
            {
                sort: 1,
                name: 'name1',
                img : 'mezon1',

            },
                {
                sort: 1,
                name: 'name2',
                img : 'mezon2',

            }

    ]
 }
});
```

But it's not working and Laravel gives me this error :
*FatalErrorException .. unexpected '{'*

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

chenge it to

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <img src="{{asset('assets/img/')}}@{{ item.name }}">
</div>
```

Comment: It returns just <img>

Answer (score 0):

Angular and blade (laravel template engine) are conflicting on the use of "{" and "}". You should configure the one or the other to use another interpolation characters.

Have a look on https://scotch.io/tutorials/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs

Comment: I can use Angular with @ before {{